# Copy contents of image file to the clipboard using gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm writing a gulp task to do the following:

- Watch an image file for changes
- If image file has changed, copy the contents of the image to the clipboard, ready for me to paste.

Note: I'm on Windows and am using nircmd.exe to do the copy of the image contents. The following command line works for me:

```
nircmd.exe clipboard copyimage "G:\IMG\pic.png"
```

I've put this into a **.bat** file so I can run the file via commandline.

My gulpfile (so far):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    shell = require('gulp-shell'),
    run = require('gulp-run'),
    clipboard = require("gulp-clipboard"),
    myTerminal = require("child_process").exec,
    commandToBeExecuted = "./copy-to-clipboard.bat";

gulp.task('copy-to-clipboard', function () {
    require('child_process').spawn('cmd', ['/s', '/c', '"G:\\Git\\copy-to-clipboard\\copy-to-clipboard.bat"'], { 
      windowsVerbatimArguments: true
    });
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    watch('watch/*.png','copy-to-clipboard');
});
```

I've tried **gulp-shell** but since this opens a node terminal, **nircmd.exe** is not recognised as an internal or external command.

I've also tried **child_process** (both spawn and exec), but while I get no errors, the contents are still not in the clipboard.

Is there an easier way or is this just not possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like its trying to run it if you are getting a

```
    nircmd.exe is not recognised as an internal or external command.
```

error.

I would add nircmd.exe to your path to fix it.
or in your bat file you could do something like:

```
    c:\path\to\program\nircmd.exe
```

that might fix it to.

If you are going to use nircmd that much I would just add it to your path.